# Java - Suggestions on how to remove an element that meets a certain condition?

Tags: java

I'm trying to remove certain elements from an array that are either less than 0 or larger than 250. I've read about arrayUtils.removeElement, but it doesn't seem to work (ArrayUtils cannot be resolved). Any suggestions to what I can use?

These are the imported libraries:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public static void dataCleaning() {
  readFile();
  int[] heights = readFile();
  int[] myArray[];
  for (int i = 0; i < heights.length; i++) {
    if (heights[i] > 250 || heights[i] < 0) {
      ArrayUtils.removeElement(heights, heights[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ArrayUtils is a library from apache (commons-lang). You need to download it and add it to your project/classpath.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One, you should probably only call `readFile` once. Don't read it twice to throw the first one away. Second, you can use an `IntStream` to `filter` the values you want to keep and remove the values you want to ignore (before building a new array - I would not remove elements in a loop, an array has a fixed size - so each of those operations creates a new array).

Instead, I'd do it like,

```
public static void dataCleaning() {
    int[] heights = readFile();
    int[] myArray = IntStream.of(heights).filter(x -> x >= 0 && x <= 250).toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here `ArrayUtils` is a library provided by apache (commons-lang), you can use `java.util.Arrays` and `java.util.stream.*`

```
int[] newArray = Arrays.stream(heights).filter(x -> x >= 0 && x <= 250).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can make another array for storing new elements.LIKE:

```
   public static void dataCleaning(){
       int[] heights = readFile();
       int[] myArray;

       int[] newArray;
       int newArrayIndex=0;
       for (int i = 0; i < heights.length; i++) {
            if (heights[i] > 250 || heights[i] < 0) {
                newArray[newArrayIndex]=heights[i];
                newArrayIndex++;
            }
       }
   }
```

Edited:
Or you can edit heights array also just use it in place of newArray with newArrayIndex .

Comment: You need a `newArrayIndex++` somewhere; and you should also tell OP how to size the `newArray` appropriately.